# How to direct a user to a specific screen with a notification in expo-router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications, expo-router

how do you actually make a user go to a particular screen when clicking on a notification in expo-router?

I know it is said to be automatically handled by expo-router but I lack a piece of information to make it work.

So, is there any specific things to set up ? what should be in the notif format/data ?

Comment: Hope [this](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/receiving-notifications/) is helpful for you!

Comment: thanks man! I thought I needed something more but nope.. a simple router.replace() inside the event listener does it